# Smooth zooming in viewport

Tags: interface

I have experience with Maya and C4D and I’ve become very accustomed to the way view-port navigation works in them. I know that one can set the key-mapping to that of industry standard; however then the orthographic views’ key-maps on the numpad gets changed (which is a no no).

So I’ve set up different key-mapping for camera panning and rotating on the Blender key-maps **but** I want to add the function to smooth zoom via <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>RIGHT CLICK</kbd> and dragging the mouse **up** and/or **down**. I know that it is mapped to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>MIDDLE MOUSE</kbd> on the default Blender key-map.

I realize I can just go into the settings and do it manually but I’m afraid of effing it up too much. So I’m hoping that someone here might have already sorted this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that zooming for sure if you know how to add a new keymap:

Go in that keymap setting panel and choose the **3D-view(global)** panel, scroll down to see that `Add New` Button. Press it, it will give you a `None` keymap.

Setting up the **identifier field** with the thing you want, in the zoom case `view3d.zoom`

[image]

And then setup rest of the key setting, you shouldn't need other details setting for your task.

Comment: worth also mentioning that there is a setting in the Preferences under `Navigation`, section `Zoom`, where Zoom Axis can be defined as either Vertical or Horizontal, since the OP is asking explicitly for an up/down movement.

Comment: Thanks Hikariztw, I'll try it out.

I also tried just changing the mapping on **Zoom View** under **3D View (Global)** to _Alt Right Mouse_ and that works perfectly fine.